# Can't delete an IBM Bluemix Organization

Tags: ibm-cloud

This page https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/orgs_spaces.html says I can delete an existing organization or space, but I can't do that on either modern or classic version of dashboard.

[image: dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Bluemix Support, you cannot currently delete an organization. However, you can complete one of these actions:

- Rename the organization to an org name that you can use
- Rename is to a name that you can use to distinguish it from active organizations.